# Using C++ libraries while extending python with C++

Tags: python, c++, distutils

I made a program in C++ and I would like to make a python module out of it. So far I have created an example project to test what I have learned so far. I've managed to make a hello world module in python that runs fine and it has some other C++ files too. I've added them like this:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('my_test',
                    sources = ['py_extend.cpp', 'src/a_source_file.cpp'])

setup (name = 'python_test',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a demo package',
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

But the project I want to originally convert to python uses a lot of libraries, such as opencl for kernel level operations. OpenGL for some graphic stuff, ffmpeg for video rendering, opencv for processing those videos etc. My question is, how do I add those modules to my python module since I can't use cmake?

I'm aware that there are other tools for this task but I want to do it the official python way.

Edit: Also on a side note even though it works just fine, without the use of cmake VSCode gives me this error:

[image]

Can I get rid of it without disabling errors?

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html)?

Comment: @n.m. Hmm I did not take distutils docs into considiration. This might help, thanks! Can you still give me a minimal reproducible example though?